# How to find an element in an array of a document in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find

I have a code like the following.

```
router.get('/Child_Profile/:SchoolId/:childId',function(req,res,next){
childModel.find({"schoolid":req.params.SchoolId,"students[]":req.params.ChildId}, function (err, result) {       
        if (err) 
            {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    res.json(result);
        });
  });
```

**Ex Collection**

```
{
"schoolid":"1wer",
"students":["121","232"],
"profilepic":"http://wed"
}
```

While i am finding the student info using schoolid and studentid the above schema was finding with only schoolid, not with the studentid. Thanks in advance

Comment: Am "students":["121,232"], maybe should be "students":["121" , "232"]? you have there string "121,232" do you search using that value or 121?

Comment: Even though, i used $and it was comparing with schoolid only. I used like the following   childModel.find({$and:[{"schoolid":req.params.SchoolId},{"students[]":req.params.ChildId}]}, function (err, result) {

Comment: yeah..its "students":["121","232"]

Answer (score 1):

You have reffered `students as an array - students[]`, use just students and pass on the value of the studentid, the query will return you results.

```
Mongo shell query for the collection

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59e9cfd4f4896dbabfc15f45"),
        "schoolid" : "1wer",
        "students" : [
                "121",
                "232"
        ],
        "profilepic" : "http://wed"
}

db.collection.find({students:"121"});
```

Modified query

```
router.get('/Child_Profile/:SchoolId/:childId',function(req,res,next){
childModel.find({"schoolid":req.params.SchoolId,"students":req.params.ChildId}, function (err, result) {       
        if (err) 
            {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    res.json(result);
        });
  });
```

Comment: Please check on the value of `req.params.ChildId` and also to check the query you can pass the value directly(here `"students":"123"` and see what is the result.

Comment: Yeah...Its working.Thanks Dude....Actually, the mistake was instead of ChildId, i gave childId.